# Do all versions of Windows 7 include version 3.5 of the .NET Framework?

Tags: .net, .net-3.5, windows-7

Do all versions of Windows 7 include version 3.5 of the .NET Framework?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

According to postings on MSDN forums (such as http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/netfxsetup/thread/347bc59c-374c-43f9-a2ed-e9bb89c6f25b), Windows 7 includes the .NET Framework 3.5.1.

However, it's an optional install (probably more correctly it can be disabled):

> For Windows 7, it includes the .NET Framework 3.5.1 as an OS component. This means you will get the .NET Framework 2.0 SP2, 3.0 SP2 and 3.5 SP1 plus a few post 3.5 SP1 bug fixes if you have installed Windows 7. Thus, you don't need to manually install .NET 3.5 with SP1. We can add or remove the feature of 3.5 with SP1 via the Programs and Features control panel.

Microsoft should really have some official documentation that makes this clear somewhere, but this is the best I could dig up.

Answer (score 5):

[Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.NET_Framework) says that 3.0 is installed in Windows 7.  I thought 3.5 was on it though...

I think Wikipedia isn't correct.  If you look at the [.NET 3.5 SP1 download page](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?familyid=AB99342F-5D1A-413D-8319-81DA479AB0D7&displaylang=en), it doesn't list Windows 7 as a supported operating system.  I think that's because it's included with Win7.  Also makes sense because 3.5 SP1 was released 11/18/2008, and Win7 was released almost a year later.

Comment: Wikipedia seems to correct now: [.NET Framework - Versions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.NET_Framework#Versions) Version 3.0 of the .NET Framework is included with Windows Server 2008 and Windows Vista. Version 3.5 is included with Windows 7, and can also be installed on Windows XP and the Windows Server 2003 family of operating systems.