# Build Error in VS 2008 Setup Project

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2008, installation

When I build a visual studio 2008 setup project, I get the following warning:

"Could not find prerequisite '.NET Framework 3.5 SP1' in path 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v6.0A\Bootstrapper\'"

There is not a Bootstrapper folder under my v6.0A folder. Do I need one? Is this warning important? The project's .msi file seems to work fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is for creating the setup.exe which ensures all prerequisites for your application are installed.  It doesn't affect your msi.

You can change your prerequisites by going to the properties of your setup project, click prerequisites button on the bottom right, and set the install location to download from the vendors site.

You can also disable the creation of this file by unchecking the top checkbox in the prerequisites window.

Comment: The install location was already set to the vendor's site. It seems like that should prevent this warning, but it doesn't. When I unchecked the top check box, that got rid of the warning. In that configuration, what happens when someone without framework 3.5 installs the application? Will everybody (windows 7 and up) already have framework 3.5?

Comment: They won't be able to install it without framework 3.5 since it's a prerequisite on your msi.  I'm not sure if the error message will explicitly say .net 3.5 is missing or if it says a generic prerequisite is missing.  You can test it yourself by uninstalling .net 3.5.  According to this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2080142/do-all-versions-of-windows-7-include-version-3-5-of-the-net-framework Windows 7 and up should have .net 3.5 already installed.

Answer (score 1):

You may try to download [this](http://download.microsoft.com/download/A/2/8/A2807F78-C861-4B66-9B31-9205C3F22252/VS2008SP1Readme.htm#General%20Issues).

Also you may try to follow the directions in 2.3.1.1 Enable Samesite for the .NET Framework 3.5 SP1 bootstrapper package

Comment: This does not help, possibly because there is no product.xml file in the dotNetFx35.exe download. (There was not even a folder for it before I followed those directions.)