# Visual Studio 2012 project retargeted from .NET 4.5 to 3.5 cannot find framework on Windows 7

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2012, .net-3.5, .net-4.5

I just retargeted a project from .NET 4.5 to 3.5 to accommodate the client machine. I did the following to do so:

- .csproj target version changed
- appconfig supported runtime version changed
- Enabled the .NET Framework 3.5.1 in Windows Features

I also found a [visual studio 2012 patch](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=36020) which supposedly contained a fix for running older versions.

Despite doing these things, I still get the following error when attempting to run the project:

[image]

[image]

Am I missing anything?

[Edit:] Added config and csproj sections

[image]

[image]

Comment: The sku attribute should only be used for .NET Framework versions >= 4.0

Answer (score 0):

I just made a downgrade in my .net project (4.0 to 3.5) and I only in the project properties change in the Application tab the target framework, then I have to change some assemblies(bad versions), then rebuild, and  in my case, cause I want to create a site in my IIS, I create a pool aplication with ASP .NET v2.0. And it works. It in Visual 2010.

I dont have to modify anything else, I didnt touch the web.config.

I hope that in some way my case help you.

Answer (score 0):

Try these:

1. Update web.config where ever you used " Version=4.0.0.0", update to  "Version=3.5.0.0 " also you have to update public token of that. Also you have to remove "compilerVersion" attribute from web.config.
2. In VS go to Project Properies, Select "Application" Tab. There is one dropdown "Target Framework" make it to ".Net Framework 3.5".
3. Update reference if you have given of any library which is complied into 4.0.

If you are still getting the error when you try and run the web site make sure the targetFramework attribute is removed from the web.config as all other framework versions earlier than 4.0 do not require "TargetFramework" attribute. See [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb398202.aspx) and another [SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2080142/do-all-versions-of-windows-7-include-version-3-5-of-the-net-framework).

Hope this helps.