# Bumped my application's target framework down to .NET 2.0 so it would work on stock Win 7 machines, side effects?

Tags: vb.net, frameworks

My end users cannot install .NET framework on their systems due to restrictions they face, so I was looking for another solution to where they could use my software.

I ended up bumping the target Framework down to 2.0 from 4.5.1 and it worked with no issues on their computers.

HOWEVER, I get a bunch of "warnings" in Visual Studio about

```
Warning 12  The primary reference "Microsoft.ReportViewer.WinForms, could not be resolved because it has an indirect dependency on the framework assembly
```

though it doesn't stop the program from compiling or running.

I distribute the program by placing the output of my debug folder in a share folder on a server so they can run it without installing.

Will there be any consequences to using an older target framework? What's the highest framework I can use in order to avoid installing it, in other words, what's the highest framework that comes stock with Windows 7?

Comment: I am not 100% sure about this, but I think it's at least .NET Framework 3.5.

Comment: Thanks. How will I know if I add a line of code incompatible with the target framework? Should I be concerned about the warning messages I am getting if all is working?

Comment: Yep, a quick Google search gave me the answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/2080211/3740093

Comment: If you add a code line that is not compatible with the chosen Framework you will get an error and be unable to compile the application, OR you will get an exception while running it. It doesn't matter if it's supported in 4.5.1 and you have 4.5.1, if you've chosen 3.5 it will run under 3.5 on your computer too. - Though I don't know if you need to worry about the warnings.

Comment: Excellent thanks, that will be helpful when testing end user compatibility on my own machine.

Comment: .NET 2.0 went dodo quite a while ago.  In the real world, the machine always has at least .NET 3.5 SP1.  Like any Win7 machine, it comes pre-installed.

Comment: @HansPassant Thanks, I tried that and it worked.